# Creating different GUID for same lowercase and upper case strings

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, guid

When I try to create GUIDs like this

```
Guid guid1 = Guid.Parse("aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-eeee-ffffffffffff");
Guid guid2 = Guid.Parse("AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-EEEE-FFFFFFFFFFFF");
```

Both are creating same GUID object. Is it possible to create unique GUIDs for lower case and upper case version of same string?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: GUIDs are actually bytes parsed from hexadecimal.  That is not possible.

Comment: Just out of interest, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Slaks: Please post that as an answer so that I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: @MikeyMouse: We have a requirement in which we keep GUIDs to uniquely identify some objects. Unfortunately we need to be able to sync these between Mac and PC. I guess Mac can handle such situation. I wanted to be able to be in sync with Mac version.

Comment: @VibhoreTanwer If anything returns two Guid objects from those strings which are not identical in every way then its not a Guid. The strings are a hexadecimal representation of 128 bytes of binary data. Hexadecimal does not assign different values to upper and lower case letters as I'm sure you know.

Comment: @VibhoreTanwer However it's technically possible that in a language where Guid is a reference type that guid1 will not equal guid2 but that does not mean they are not the same guid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GUIDs are actually bytes parsed from hexadecimal.
That is not possible.

You should not use GUIDs to store arbitrary data.

Comment: It's worth noting that ITU REC X.667 https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.667-201210-I/en which covers UUIDS states in section 6.5.4 `"Software generating the hexadecimal representation of a UUID shall not use upper case letters.
NOTE – It is recommended that the hexadecimal representation used in all human-readable formats be restricted to lower-case
letters. Software processing this representation is, however, required to accept both upper and lower case letters as specified
in 6.5.2."`  So when generating them, it's advisable to use only lower case letters.

Answer (score 8):

Your strings are hexadecimal representations of the same value because hexadecimal is not case sensitive.

Your request is like saying that you don't want `0.5` to equal `1 / 2`. They are different representations of the same value.

Perhaps you need a different method of generating GUIDs.

Comment: Great example with decimal / fraction. Had an argument with a customer once about whether .30 == 1/2 (b/c they were tracking half hours in a time system)